# I fail to fetch GPG keys over HKPS with "gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 1: unsupported protocol" error

Tags: gpg

I'm trying to fetch some GPG keys over keys.gnupg.net and hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net and both fails with:

```
gpg: requesting key 1F41B907 from hkps server hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 1: unsupported protocol
```

I'm using Debian testing. `gpg --version` yields `gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.16`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For some reason or another I need to install the `gnupg-curl` to get SSL support over HKP:

> This package contains the keyserver helper tools built with libcurl,
>    which replace the ones in the gnupg package built with the "curl shim"
>    variant of gnupg. **This package provides support for HKPS keyservers.**

Installing it solved the issue.